# Laravel / Postgres - How to group by one column and select multiple columns?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, query-builder

I have FOR EXAMPLE laravel query builder:

`DB::table('users')->select('name', 'phone', 'age')->groupBy('age')->...`

How to do this query work?
The problem is that postgres can't group only by one column like mysql

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as properly formatted text (not images, not links.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values into summary rows, like "find the number of customers in each country".

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

DEMO:

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country;
```

[image]

SQL query, that was suggested by you, doesn't work as you expect. You can demonstrate the result what you expect, maybe I misunderstood you.